# Replacing elements from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that will pass the following test
"test.testEqual(replace_chars(" SampIEam*", ["p", "E", "*"]), " Sam I am ")". A list of characters will be removed from a string and pass the test.

I came up with this code

```
"""

import test

def replace_chars(tmpStr, tmpChar):
    tmpWord = " ".join(tmpChar)
    newWord = " "
    for item in tmpStr:
        if item not in tmpStr:
            newWord = newWord + item
        else:
            newWord = newWord + " "
    return item
test.testEqual(replace_chars("SamplEam*",["p","E","*"]), "Sam l am ")
```

The result was `Test Failed: expected Sam l am  but got *`

Newbie here, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def replace_chars(tmpStr, tmpChar):
    for i in tmpChar:
        tmpStr = tmpStr.replace(i, " ")
    return tmpStr
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, but is it possible to do with Join or Split or any other list methods?

Answer (score 0):

If for some strange reason(maybe a homework) you really need to use `split` and `join` you could write it as this

```
def replace_chars(tmpStr, tmpChar) :
    for c in tmpChar:
        if c not in tmpStr: continue
        tmp = " ".join(tmpStr.split(c))
        if tmpStr[-1] == c: 
            tmpStr += " "
        # I'm not really sure if the "if" above is necessary
        # responding from my phone, can't test it 
        tmpStr = tmp
    return tmpStr
```

This is purely academic, the answer @Rakesh provided is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using joins also.

```
def replace_chars(tmpStr, tmpChar):
  s = "".join(char if char not in tmpChar else ' ' for char in tmpStr)
  return s
```